# Different Firefox menu on windows and linux

Tags: firefox

What is the reason why Firefox has different menus on Windows and Linux?

For example, on Windows you reach browser settings via `Tools->Options` while on Linux you go to `Edit->Preferences` for same functionality.

Is it purely because of tradition or is there some deeper reason behind this?
It seems more like a nuisance, especially for someone who is frequently using both systems.

Comment: [Related Mozilla KB article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Menu_differences_in_Windows,_Linux,_and_Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Different environments have different standards. The standard for Windows is **Tools** > **Options**, while the standard for GNOME/Linux is **Edit** > **Preferences**. In my opinion, this is how it should be. For example, when I am working in Windows, I would not want an application (which also has a Mac OSX version) to move the Minimize/Maximize/Close buttons to the left side of the window.

Comment: Then there are a lot of broken standards :[. Photoshop on Windows is using `Edit->Preferences` and NetBeans on Linux is using `Tools->Options`... But at least in these cases the design of one programm stays the same on different systems. I find it easier to get used to. I also imagine that it is easier for a company to maintain one standard per software piece, rather than per OS.